# Mono throws System.LoadTypeException for target, but target runs fine by itself

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mono

I have a mono/.NET application that I am trying to run with mono. The app runs just fine on its own, but when I try to run it with mono (i.e., `<path to mono> <path to target>`), there are problems.

I used the `--debug` flag to get more information about the issue, and I received this output:

> The entry point method could not be loaded due to Could not load file or assembly > 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' > or one of its dependencies.

So I did a search for "PresentationFramework" on my filesystem and found a DLL in the Microsoft.NET directory. I just copied the DLL over to my target app directory and tried again. This produced the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not set up parent
> class, due to: Could not load type of field
> 'System.Windows.Application:_mainWindow' (20) due to: Could not load
> file or assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
> assembly:<path_to_target>\PresentationFramework.dll
> type:Application member:(null) [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
> System.TypeLoadException: Could not set up parent class, due to: Could
> not load type of field 'System.Windows.Application:_mainWindow' (20)
> due to: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationCore,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
> one of its dependencies. assembly:<path_to_target>PresentationFramework.dll
> type:Application member:(null)

To me, it appears that the system tried to load a file called "PresentationCore" and failed. So I did a search for that file and found another DLL. I copy and pasted it into my app directory and tried again. This time, I got the following error:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not set up parent class, due to: Could
> not load type of field 'System.Windows.Application:_appMimeType' (24)
> due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000069 from typeref
> (expected class 'MS.Internal.SecurityCriticalDataForSet`1' in assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35') assembly:WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 type:MS.Internal.SecurityCriticalDataForSet`1 member:(null)
> assembly:<path_to_target>\PresentationFramework.dll type:Application
> member:(null) [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
> System.TypeLoadException: Could not set up parent class, due to: Could
> not load type of field 'System.Windows.Application:_appMimeType' (24)
> due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000069 from typeref
> (expected class 'MS.Internal.SecurityCriticalDataForSet`1' in assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35') assembly:WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 type:MS.Internal.SecurityCriticalDataForSet`1 member:(null)
> assembly:<path_to_target>\PresentationFramework.dll type:Application
> member:(null)

At this point, I have no idea what else to try. I am running Mono version 6.12.0, built with Visual Studio on Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

There was never a complete WPF implementation on Mono and/or .NET Core. So, the exception you met is simply by design.

Avalonia just announced its cross platform WPF implementation, https://avaloniaui.net/XPF So that can be the only option for you if you want to stick to that technology.